# Importar DLL do Python no C++

Tags: python, c++, dll

Como faço para compilar uma classe do Python em DLL para poder importar ela no C++, usando recursos do Python que não estão disponíveis no C++?

Eu quero poder importar ela sem ter o Python instalado no computador

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python não é uma linguagem *"compilada"*, é uma linguagem *"interpretada"*, ou seja mesmo programas como py2exe ou cx_freeze enviam uma versão stand-alone do Python junto com a versão *"compilada do Python"* em EXE e o source (ou o `pyd` que é uma linguagem intermediaria) do Python provavelmente esta interno (depende de cada programa, não os conheço a fundo).

Ou seja é meio que impossível criar um .dll do uma aplicação Python que não precise do Python, a não ser que exista um conversor do Python para "C" ou "C++" que é depois compilado de fato, mas seria bem complicado, o trabalho seria tanto que talvez nem valha a pena, seria mais fácil escrever em C++ mesmo.

Posso dizer quase seguramente que a ausência de certas funcionalidade no C++ que supostamente você tem no Python podem ser obtidas através de .libs ou até sources que você encontrará em repositórios.

Existem também programas com uma quantidade bem avançada de funcionalidade para C++ como o https://qt.io que tem versão open-source e enterprise. O Qt tem IDE, SDK e recursos opicionais, compila para Mingw, MSVC, GCC, tem port pra Android, iOS ou seja ele é um SDK cross-platform.

Eu presumo que o seu motivo para fazer isto não é a *"ausência somente"*, mas sim a sua familiariade com a linguagem e com projetos desenvolvidos nela, você deve conhecer bem Python, mas não C++ e provavelmente você esta querendo escrever em Python por já conhecer, logo lhe digo que esse caminho (do meu ponto de vista) é o das pedras, eu sugiro que você ou opte por escrever tudo em Python mesmo e usar programas como:

- http://www.pyinstaller.org
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze
- http://www.py2exe.org

Que irão criar um executável do teu script incluindo um "python stand-alone"

Ou então que você se aventure no Qt, que possui muitas funcionalidade de maneira simplificada para realizar muitas coisas e ainda é cross-platform.